# Using motioncells in gstreamer on a armboard (rock 4, tinker-board)

Tags: debian, gstreamer, debian-buster

I am trying to experiment with motioncells in gstreamer (motion detection) but getting the message: Errounus pipeline: no element 'motioncells'.

According to Gstreamer documentation this plugin is in the gst-plugins-bad list which I have installed (along with open-cv and gst plugins good & base) but neither gst-launch or gst-inspect can find it.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opencv/motioncells.html?gi-language=c#motioncells-page

https://packages.debian.org/buster/libs/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad

Could it be that this version of debian buster does not have this particular plugin?